# Google Earth Engine Python API: Map function over image collection with a list of bands

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-python-api, sentinel2

I have been using the code by [Sam Murphy](https://github.com/samsammurphy/gee-atmcorr-S2) for atmospheric correction of Sentinel-2 images in Google Earth Engine. All goes well and it runs very fast for a single image. What I would like to do is map the following code over an image collection:

```
output = image.select('QA60')
for band in ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B10','B11','B12']:
    print(band)
    output = output.addBands(surface_reflectance(band))
```

I think I need a double map function for this (to avoid using the for-loop here), but have not seen any Python examples in GEE yet.

So far this is what I have come up with:

```
def atcorrector(image):
    qa = image.select('QA60')
    bands = ee.List(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B10','B11','B12'])
    def mapper(bands):
        return qa.map(addBands(surface_reflectance(bands)))
    return qa

ImageCollection.map(atcorrector)
```

However this does not return image with all the bands, so I feel that my nested function does not work properly. I am new to python, so all help is appreciated!

Side-Note: I have already experimented with Sam's [second repository](https://github.com/samsammurphy/ee-atmcorr-timeseries) for atmospheric correction over image collections, but it runs far too slowly and I would prefer to have a 'server-side' computation using a proposed map function as I have loads of images to process.

PS: Below is the code for the `surface_reflectance` function, as extracted from Sam Murphy's Repository. It calls on one of his customised classes called "Atmospheric". The model used for atmospheric correction is the Py6S model.

```
# Package requirement
from Py6S import * 
import datetime
import math
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()),'bin'))
from atmospheric import Atmospheric #Custom-defined class by Sam
import ee
ee.Initialize()

## The Sentinel-2 image collection
studyarea = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(7.8399,59.9273,8.2299,60.1208)#region of interest
S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(studyarea)\
       .filterDate('2016-06-01', '2016-06-10').sort('system:time_start')

## define metadata
info = S2one.getInfo()['properties']
scene_date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(info['system:time_start']/1000)# i.e. Python uses seconds, EE uses milliseconds
solar_z = info['MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE']
SRTM = ee.Image('USGS/GMTED2010')  # Make sure that your study area is covered by this elevation dataset
alt = SRTM.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry=studyarea.centroid()).get('be75').getInfo() # insert correct name for elevation variable from dataset
km = alt/1000  # i.e. Py6S uses units of kilometers

date = ee.Date(START_DATE)
# the following three variables are called on from the Atmospheric class Sam defined in his GitHub
h2o = Atmospheric.water(studyarea,date).getInfo() 
o3 = Atmospheric.ozone(studyarea,date).getInfo()
aot = Atmospheric.aerosol(studyarea,date).getInfo()

## Create the 6S Object
s = SixS() # Instantiate
# Atmospheric constituents
s.atmos_profile = AtmosProfile.UserWaterAndOzone(h2o,o3)
s.aero_profile = AeroProfile.Continental
s.aot550 = aot

# Earth-Sun-satellite geometry
s.geometry = Geometry.User()
s.geometry.view_z = 0               # always NADIR (I think..)
s.geometry.solar_z = solar_z        # solar zenith angle
s.geometry.month = scene_date.month # month and day used for Earth-Sun distance
s.geometry.day = scene_date.day     # month and day used for Earth-Sun distance
s.altitudes.set_sensor_satellite_level()
s.altitudes.set_target_custom_altitude(km)

# Extract spectral response function for given band name
def spectralResponseFunction(bandname):
    bandSelect = {
        'B1':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_01,
        'B2':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_02,
        'B3':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_03,
        'B4':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_04,
        'B5':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_05,
        'B6':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_06,
        'B7':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_07,
        'B8':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_08,
        'B8A':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_09,
        'B9':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_10,
        'B10':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_11,
        'B11':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_12,
        'B12':PredefinedWavelengths.S2A_MSI_13,
        }
    return Wavelength(bandSelect[bandname])

# Converts top of atmosphere reflectance to at-sensor radiance
def toa_to_rad(bandname):
    ESUN = info['SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_'+bandname]
    solar_angle_correction = math.cos(math.radians(solar_z))# solar exoatmospheric spectral irradiance
    doy = scene_date.timetuple().tm_yday
    d = 1 - 0.01672 * math.cos(0.9856 * (doy-4))# Earth-Sun distance (from day of year)
    multiplier = ESUN*solar_angle_correction/(math.pi*d**2)# conversion factor
    rad = toa.select(bandname).multiply(multiplier)# at-sensor radiance
    return rad

# Calculate surface reflectance from at-sensor radiance given waveband name
def surface_reflectance(bandname):
    s.wavelength = spectralResponseFunction(bandname)  # run 6S for this waveband
    s.run()
    # extract 6S outputs
    Edir = s.outputs.direct_solar_irradiance             #direct solar irradiance
    Edif = s.outputs.diffuse_solar_irradiance            #diffuse solar irradiance
    Lp   = s.outputs.atmospheric_intrinsic_radiance      #path radiance
    absorb  = s.outputs.trans['global_gas'].upward       #absorption transmissivity
    scatter = s.outputs.trans['total_scattering'].upward #scattering transmissivity
    tau2 = absorb*scatter                                #total transmissivity
    # radiance to surface reflectance
    rad = toa_to_rad(bandname)
    ref = rad.subtract(Lp).multiply(math.pi).divide(tau2*(Edir+Edif))
    return ref
```

Comment: You're not using your `mapper` function at all?

Comment: @Kevin yes, I am not sure how to fix it - could you point out what is wrong with the syntax? What I need is for my `atcorrector` function to take every image of an ee.ImageCollection, and apply the `surface_reflectance` function onto every band of each image.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the `surface_reflectance` function as you want, just modify the code as follow:

```
def atcorrector(image):
    qa = image.select('QA60')
    for band in ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B10','B11','B12']:
        print(band)
        qa = qa.addBands(surface_reflectance(band))
    return qa

ImageCollection.map(atcorrector)
```

As you see, this code just copies the code that you've made for a single image. The `for` loop works without any issues in Python API (in JavaScript API, I would not recommend using this). In case you don't want to use the `for` loop, just change the code a bit:

```
def atcorrector(image):
    qa = image.select('QA60')
    bands = ee.List(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B10','B11','B12'])

    def mapper(band):
        qa = qa.addBands(surface_reflectance(band))
        return band

    bands.map(mapper)
    return qa

ImageCollection.map(atcorrector)
```

The `map` function of `ee.List` (or any `ee` object that has the `map` function) could be a replacement for the `for` loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's how I tried to fix it - threw this error at me:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'qa' referenced before assignment`

Doesn't make sense since qa is specified earlier in the function? Must be something more related to the surface_reflectance function I am calling on. I suspect it does not like the ee.List format for the band names, and prefers a regular list.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.x, add `nonlocal qa` line right after the line `def mapper (band):` to give `mapper` function full access to `qa`. Without this line, `mapper` function can read `qa` but cannot modify it. It's about variable scope in Python, not the `surface_reflectance` function. How about the approach using `for` loop?

Comment: Yes! The `nonlocal qa` addition did get rid of the error. The approach using `for` loop works, it's what I've been using but is just too slow for my requirements. I was hoping that by mapping over an `ee.List` I would switch to the "server-side" computation - not sure whether that is a correct assumption to make. Now when I run it with this correct code, it says `KeyError: <ee.computedobject.ComputedObject object at 0x7f19452d2400>` - probably need to adjust the `surface_reflectance` function to accept ee.List objects too. Any ideas for making that transition? Thanks for your time btw!

Comment: What's the code of your `surface_reflectance` function?

Comment: It is quite a large code. I have edited the question to add it in full, but perhaps the notebook of the original [GitHub](https://github.com/samsammurphy/gee-atmcorr-S2) will be easier to read.